# How can I represent in R two quantitative variables and color the plot according to a categorical variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, iris-dataset

'''

```
my_data<-iris
```

'''
'''

```
length.ratio<- my_data$Sepal.Length/my_data$Petal.Length
width_ratio<-my_data$Sepal.Width/my_data$Petal.Width
```

'''
'''

```
my_data$Species<-as.factor(my_data$Species)
```

'''
#Attempt of plotting with ggplot2

'''

```
ggplot(my_data,aes(length_ratio,fill=Species))+theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(width.ratio~Species)+ geom_density(alpha=0.5)+
  labs(x="Width Ratio", y="Length Ratio")
```

'''

#Actually, I neither know which 'geom_plot' is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a scatter plot. So try this and always try to keep your variables in your dataframe. If you store your variables inside same dataframe you do not have to create a new factor. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
my_data<-iris
#Compute variables
my_data$length.ratio<- my_data$Sepal.Length/my_data$Petal.Length
my_data$width_ratio<-my_data$Sepal.Width/my_data$Petal.Width
```

The plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(my_data,aes(width_ratio,length.ratio,color=Species))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.5)+
  theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~Species,scales='free')+
  labs(x="Width Ratio", y="Length Ratio")
```

Output:

[image]

And if you want to study density try this:

```
#Plot 2
ggplot(my_data,aes(length.ratio,color=Species,fill=Species))+
  geom_density(alpha=0.5)+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: OMG, I am speechless and absolutely grateful!

Comment: Just one more aspect I would like to comment, with 'facet_wrap()' when do I have to use ' ~ ' ? AND It is important to specify 'free' for the scale?

Comment: @Christ14n97 You have to use `~` when you want to compare between two or more variables. In this case you only want one variable so it is valid to use `.~Variable`. The scales option is up to you if you want each facet with a differente scale you add `free` otherwise you can avoid it to have only a common scale. I hope that was clear enough!